# Uniform distribution in the target variable

Tags: regression, machine-learning, uniform-distribution

I'm analysing a dataset that gave some very poor regression models in the past (not trained by me). Basically, I'm trying to get insights on why those models were so bad.

The target variable is the log of raw measurements and its distribution looks like this.

[image]
I noticed that if we look at specific ranges, for a good chunk of the data (4K out of 7K samples) the target variable is close to a uniform distribution:

[image]

The QQ plot comparing to a uniform distribution also points in that direction:

[image]
I could think of someways this distribution could affect the model but I'm not sure. For instance, since the distribution is uniform it might be harder to find patterns in the data to make good predictions.

The latest random forest model trained on this data returned a residual plot like this:

[image]

I also plotted a histogram of the residuals and they seem pretty much like a normal distribution, but with a slight left skew. My interpretation is that the residuals are ok, but that descending pattern in the residual plot looks strange to me and I can't understand why it happens.

[image]

My problem is the following:

Is it right to assume that a uniform distribution of the target variable can affect the performance of the model?

What if I transform the task into a classification problem?

Comment: Note that the marginal distribution of the target variable is not very relevant for regression, as regression models the conditional distribution. So it might be more helpful for you to show us plots of *residuals*, but also tell us about your real problem!

Comment: Saying that just over half the target variable values are close to following a particular distribution may not be a helpful statement if you are carefully selecting the values to consider.  I can reach almost half following a uniform distribution if I select from a large sample from a normal distribution

Comment: Why do you think non-normality is a problem with a random forest?

Comment: The random forest residual plot looks rather typical for a situation in which there is a lower bound (probably zero, maybe larger considering the other plots) on the response variable. This will not be normally distributed, but this specific violation of normality is usually rather harmless. (Apart from the fact that for the random forest you wouldn't need to worry about normality anyway.)

Comment: Thanks @ChristianHennig. I think I got confused with the assumptions.